# Converting ASCII to UTF-8 stringi in R

Tags: r, utf-8, ascii, stringi

I have the following problem:

```
library(stringi)
x_1<-"P N001361/01"
x_2<-"Р N001361/01"
x_1==x_2
[1] FALSE

> stri_enc_mark(x_1)
[1] "ASCII"
> stri_enc_mark(x_2)
[1] "UTF-8"
```

Then I try:

```
stri_encode(x_1,"ASCII","UTF-8",to_raw=FALSE)==x_2
```

But this still does not work. Maybe somebody can suggest how to make those two strings identical (I am trying to merge x_1 by x_2).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not about conversion. The issue is the first letter of `x_2` is https://unicode-table.com/en/0420/.

That is clear when you run:

```
> stri_encode(x_2,"UTF-8", "ASCII",to_raw=FALSE)
[1] "\032 N001361/01"
Warning message:
In stri_encode(x_2, "UTF-8", "ASCII", to_raw = FALSE) :
  the Unicode codepoint \U00000420 cannot be converted to destination encoding
```

Therefore you need to explicitly convert the character to actual letter "P"

```
x_2_rep <- stri_replace_all_regex(x_2, parse(text = '\U00000420'), "P")
x_1 == x_2_rep
## TRUE
```

Comment: But what to do if I have many such strings, i.e. I have one dataset with x_1 and the second one with x_2 and I want to merge on x_2 i.e. I do not know ex ante that there will be the later P

Comment: I got this error: Error in parse(text = "<U+0420>") : <text>:1:1: unexpected '<'
1: <
    ^